# Get user specific data through AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a site in which i need to get user information from database through ajax request. There is a function `isLoggedIn()` for checking user logged in or not, if logged in it will return `user_id`.

But the problem is the function uses the session information, so how i could get authenticate in the ajax function?

Comment: Is the session set through `session_start()` in the file that your Ajax code calls?

Comment: The same way you authenticate any other HTTP request your site receives.

Comment: did you try anything ? I think you should try and show your code before you ask for answer

Comment: yea i'm using session_start()

Comment: it'll be much easier for everyone if you could show your code, so that the answer will be tailor made for you instead of a general one. (also it's much harder to help without your code)

Comment: @nnk so just use session.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time guys. I got fixed it. It was not about the session. Next time i must be more specific in asking questions. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problems to call session_start() function in an ajax request. It wont conflict with main page.

Answer (score 0):

`print_r($_SESSION);` and check that session is creating or not.